# How to get a sublist of all other elements while iterating?

Tags: python, iteration, modulo, sublist

Using list comprehension I can easily do the following:

```
l = [0, 1, 2]
for i in l:
    subl = [j for j in l if j != i]
```

Is there a non-list comprehension way to do this by manipulating indices with the `%` operator?

**Edit**

To clarify: the indices match the list elements

Comment: Wouldn't this be quicker with a combination operation? Like `import itertools; list(itertools.combination(l, len(l)-1))`?

Comment: @Abdou it's not combination, it's all the sublists that are missing one element from the original list

Comment: Your algorithm wouldn't work if you have repeating values in the list. You really should be doing this on indices (`enumerate()` may help).

Comment: You are right, I should clarify that the indices match the list elements

Comment: Why does it have to involve using the `%` operator?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that doesn't use list comprehension:

```
l = [0, 1, 2]
for i in range(len(l)):
    subl = l[:]
    subl.remove(i)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2]
[0, 2]
[0, 1]
```

Comment: That's fine, but I am looking for a way to do it with `%`

Comment: @SamHammamy that's the modulo operator, which doesn't work with lists

Comment: by the way, look at what champion wrote above (which you agreed with), isn't it exactly what this solution suggests ?

Answer (score 1):

This is completely artificial and there is really no reason for doing it this way:

```
>>> l = [0, 1, 2]
>>> n = len(l)
>>> [[l[(j+i)%n] for j in range(n-1)] for i in range(n)]
[[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0]]
```

It rotates around the list which is what `%` will do, perhaps more obvious with a longer list:

```
>>> l = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5]
>>> n = len(l)
>>> [[l[(j+i)%n] for j in range(n-1)] for i in range(n)]
[[0, 1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4, 5], [2, 4, 5, 0], [4, 5, 0, 1], [5, 0, 1, 2]]
```

If you really do need this rotational output then suggest looking into `collections.deque()`.